# How can I get the normal orientation of an edge

Tags: python

I need to get the **Normal** orientation of an edge and apply it to a new object:

```
obj = bpy.data.objects['Edge']
mat = obj.matrix_world
# Decompose object in location, rotation, scale
loc_obj, rot_obj, scl_obj = mat.decompose()
```

The method above give me the **Global** orientation:
[image: Global]

Is it possible to get a matrix containing the **Normal** orientation in the `rot_obj` component?
[image: Normal]

Thanks

Comment: The desired normal orientation is not unique. In your last picture any orientation with same y(the green one) can be a valid solution. Can you provide more constraints?